# Order of creation and initialization of object members in Javascript

Tags: javascript, initialization, executioncontext

I have some questions about order of initialization and creation of members in JS objects.
In my understanding, when any function is called, a function execution context is created. There also 2 phases in which code gets processed in those functions: creation and execution.

So, let's take this simple example:

```
function Main() {
  var a = "1";

  this.sayHello = function() {
     console.log("Hello!");
  }

  function inner() {
     var b = 2;
  }
}

new Main();
```

What are is the order in which all the members will be created and initialized?
I know how it works when we are not working with objects:

New execution context is created and added to the stack

Code is scanned for functions [the code is not evaluated unless called -- it just learns that there is a specific function there]

All variables are hoisted

**this** variable is getting assigned

Execution phase starts: code is getting executed line by line (including all variable assignments etc.; if any functions are called, another execution context is created and the process starts all over again)

Where in this list of steps **this.method** are getting created and defined?
I poked around and figured that during execution phase, if I call a **this.method** before it's actually defined, an error is thrown (meaning that instance method does not exist yet). However, if I call inside of the the instance method another instance method that is defined later in the code, everything works fine:
    function Main() {
      var a = "1";

```
  // this.sayHello() -- error!!

  this.sayHello = function() {
     this.sayHello2(); // no error (???)
     console.log("Hello!");
  }

  this.sayHello2 = function() {
     console.log("Hello2!");
  }

  function inner() {
     var b = 2;
  }
}

new Main();
```

Could anyone help me to understand when instance methods are created and when they are defined? How prototypal objects in JS make execution context different (besides changing the reference object of **this**) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sayHello` method is a reference to a function, and the function `this.sayHello` will be executed later, after `sayHello2` method will be initialized.
if you make something like this:

```
  this.sayHello = (function() {
     this.sayHello2(); //error
     console.log("Hello!");
  }).call(this);

  this.sayHello2 = function() {
     console.log("Hello2!");
  }

  function inner() {
     var b = 2;
  }
}

new Main();
```

use an iife, so that function will invoke immediately than an error will be thrown because js doesn't know about `this.sayHello2`. The same thing you can see if you will try to execute `this.sayHello()` before `this.sayHello2` method is defined.

Js interpreter haven't simply reached that code in `sayHello` function, so there is no error

Comment: I understand why it throws the error. What I'm not sure about is when the interpreter sets method references. Obviously, it should be after _this_ is defined in creation phase. Also, the fact that it throws the error means that instance methods are defined in execution phase [so, they're not being hoisted]. Does it mean though that when I'm calling a specific function on the object, the whole code in the body of the object has been executed? This is the only way, as I understand, how sayHello() may know about sayHello2() existence.

Comment: assigning is never hoisted, so these assigns are invoked in an execution phase. When you construct an object via `new` operator all the constructor body executes, and when you execute a method of the constructed object of course everything in the body has been assigned and calculated

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. So, is this order right?
1) New execution context
2) Functions are found and declared
3) Vars are hoisted
4) _this_ is set
5) Body of the object is executed, so all instance methods get declared (as I understand engine does not read their body unless they are called)

So, if we call a method of object, it means that the instance members are already available.
If at execution phase we try to call an instance method (which is a function expression) before it's actually declared, an error is thrown